# Asp.net Dropdownlist Page_Load isPostBack = False

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, postback

I've asked this question before in a similar manner, the the question still remains unsolved. I have a dropdownlist, populated by a local database. When a users selects an option, the page refresh and the index is set back to the first option. When this happens the SelectedIndexChanged method does not fire, when debugging, I have found that on the page load, !isPostBack is always true.

I have enableviewstate true for the page, dropdownlist and for the database as well.
along with AutoEventWireUp true for the page.

Please help, I've been stick on this one problem for about a week now!
I feel the problem may persist in my master page or the web.config file, so ill post those as well

Index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<BenchmarkApp.Models.Benchmark>>" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="true"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged);  

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Write("Post Back is False");
        bindData();
    }
}

protected void bindData()
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Version";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write((sender as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text);
    Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
}

</script>

<html>

<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Benchmark</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="bmform" runat="server">

<p>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
</p>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Build version:
        </th>
        <th>
            <%-- Html.DropDownList("Builds", null, new {@onchange = "onChange(this.value);" }) --%>
            <%-- Html.DropDownList("BuildID", (SelectList) ViewBag.Builds, "--Select One--") --%>
            <%-- Html.DropDownList("BuildDD", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Builds, "--Select One--") --%>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Version"
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                DataValueField="Id">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DAContext %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Version] FROM [Builds]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </th>
        <th>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text= "--Build Version--"></asp:Label>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Script.Name) %>
        </th>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Build.Version) %>
        </th>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MinTime) %>
        </th>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MeanTime) %>
        </th>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MaxTime) %>
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Script.Name) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Build.Version) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MinTime) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MeanTime) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MaxTime) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.BenchmarkID }) %>
            |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.BenchmarkID }) %>
            |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.BenchmarkID }) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/favicon.ico") %>" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/css") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</head>
<body>

<form id="master" runat="server">

    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"><%: Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home") %></p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    <%: Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") %>
                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") %></li>
                        <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") %></li>
                        <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home") %></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FeaturedContent" runat="server" />
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptsSection" runat="server" />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"  type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>

<!--
    Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
    after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
    MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
    To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
    controller or action.
-->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
    pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Why are you mixing MVC and WebForms?

Comment: Please don't repost [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834885/asp-net-dropdownlist-ispostback-is-alwasy-false) just because you didn't get answers.  Feel free to use the "edit" link on that question to update it with any new information you've gained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you are unable to use asp control in a MVC application. (well it didn't work for me). Instead i switched my application to use the Razor Engine and typed this in the View.cshtml:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("FilterBenchmarks", "Benchmark", FormMethod.Post))
{

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Build version:
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DropDownList("BuildID", (SelectList) ViewBag.Builds, "--Select One--", new {@onchange = "this.form.submit()"})
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And in the controller page:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FilterBenchmarks(FormCollection form)
    {
        var buildId = Convert.ToInt32(form["BuildID"]);
        var benchmarks = db.Benchmarks.Where(b => b.BuildID == buildId).Include(b => b.Build).Include(b => b.Script);

        var query = db.Builds.Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Version });
        ViewBag.Builds = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Version");

        return View("Index", benchmarks.ToList());
    }
```

This did work for me and now everything is working fine! I want to thank the people that suggested various solutions, they led me to rethink the scenario!
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

With the code as presented, it's very difficult to replicate the exact problem you're having. However, a few simple steps should eliminate the issue.

Firstly, in `Page_Load()` you're running `bindData` to link your dropdown to the data. However, your DropDown list already links to it:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Version"
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            DataValueField="Id">
```

I would suggest removing the `DataSource`, `DataValueField` etc attributes from the tag, as they are superfluous.

Secondly, as mentioned you are performing your binding in `Page_Load()`. Certain processes - including setting the currently selected item - happen between `Page_Init()` finishing and `Page_Load()` starting, so you may find moving your call to `bindData()` into `Page_Init()` will also work.

Finally, your `Page_Load()` starts with:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged += 
                       new EventHandler(DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

but your tag contains the attribute `onselectedindexchanged` already, so you're probably going to end up running `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged()` twice. Remove one of them for a bit more efficiency.

Comment: The OP is using MVC and trying to use asp control.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my problem quickly! much appreciated! I have tried everything you suggested and still no luck. I understand its hard to replicate the situation. and thats why i cant solve the problem, im not to experienced with asp.net at all, and i feel the problem is not in my code, but else where. Perhaps my settings, or configuration of some sort.

Comment: @afzalulh I realise that, yes. I just don't believe that that is his problem - mixing the two is possible.

Comment: No, this type of mixing is not possible.

Comment: Really? so how do i go about writing the code? Im very sorry, very new to ASP.net and MVC

Comment: MVC works in a different way. There are many tutorials available.You may check this one: [Intro to ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4).

Comment: @afzalulh I've managed to write a test ASPX page, in an MVC4 site, similar to the one written by the OP (but, working!); see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288840/asp-net-mvc-alongside-web-forms-in-the-same-web-app

Comment: Thank you both!! I'll check out both links!